# Merge mysql rows on conditions

Tags: mysql

I have a table like :

```
id_rel | id_art | id_fam | id_cat | id_scat | id_marca | id_model | id_year

  1      cw001      10       11        21       null       null       null
  2      cw001     null     null      null      233        455        466
```

for a particular search query i need to combine it  in a mysql view like this:

```
id_rel | id_art | id_fam | id_cat | id_scat | id_marca | id_model | id_year

  1      cw001      10       11         21       233       455        466
```

So i have to 'delete' the null values and combine the values.
Can someone explain if it's possibile and the best way to do that?

Explanation of first table : here i have some products (id_art) and family,category,subfamily relationship and in the second row brand model year relationship.
The website that use this table i have two kind of search, search for family-category-subfamily or search for brands-models-years,i need to combine them so when i'm in a family of products i have to be able to see all models,brands and years related to article.

I hope to be clear,sorry for my english
Thanks

Comment: It's a bit hard to say what you'd need to do without more details. It seems like you'd want to use a group by id_art, along with aggregate functions (e.g max, etc.) but without more details it's hard to give you anything better than what Thomas is suggesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, the `MAX()` function will discard `null` values. So you could do something like:

```
SELECT
    id_rel,
    id_art,
    MAX(id_fam),
    MAX(id_cat),
    MAX(id_scat),
    MAX(id_marca),
    MAX(id_model),
    MAX(id_year)
FROM
    table_name
GROUP BY
    id_art;
```

This assumes, of course, that the values will only ever be `1` or `null`. If you start introducing other values, it's [potentially] a little harder.

Comment: I might suggest placing an aggregate on `id_rel`, since it is not in the `group by` MySQL will select whatever value to return.  Using an aggregate will make the value more predictable.

Comment: i need to introduce other values always numbers but not only 1 or null,i'm sorry my fault to build the example

Comment: Good point @bluefeet. I'd just assumed that that value didn't matter, but yes, something like `MIN(id_rel)` would make things more predictable.

Comment: @StefanoSchivari If there is only ever a single value for each `id_fam`, `id_cat`, etc... then this solution still works. For example, if cw001 has three rows, and those rows have `id_fam` values of: `null`, `null`, and `5`... Then you're ok, because the `MAX` will be `5`. However, if the values are: `null`, `5`, and `20`... Then you'll run into problems (i.e. which is correct? `5` or `20`?).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    id_rel,
    id_art,
    COALESCE(SUM(id_fam),0),
    COALESCE(SUM(id_cat),0),
    COALESCE(SUM(id_scat),0),
    COALESCE(SUM(id_marca),0),
    COALESCE(SUM(id_model),0),
    COALESCE(SUM(id_year),0)
FROM
    table_name
GROUP BY
    id_art;
```

Would sum or give 0.

Could you give a more complex example to make sure we get the correct SQL